# Continue SESSION after Login in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple login page on my subdomain name 
"login.domainname.com" and two different folders

1. Customer_Portal
2. include

front end index.php where the login form is available on the main folder of login.domainname.com, and I am validating the login session in the ***include/validate_login.php*** folder. which is working fine in that folder.

include/validate_login.php file has:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $data['id'];
print_r($_SESSION['user']); //value is coming
```

Once login is successful I need to redirect it to ***../Customer_Portal/*** folder with session variables from include/ folder. But in ***Customer_Portal/dashboard.php*** session data is not coming and it's redirecting back to the index.php file.

dashboard.php file has:

```
session_start();
/*if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("Location: ../index.php"); exit();
}*/   // If I uncomment, it will redirect back to index.php file.

$login_session_id = $_SESSION['user'];
print_r($login_session_id); // login_session_id is blank
```

Please suggest me, what I am doing wrong with this?

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Are you call `session_start` function in validate_login.php ?

Comment: @tadman thank you for the suggestion. I am not familiar with Frameworks so I am doing it in CORE PHP but I will look into your suggestion.

Comment: @aidinMC No. Do I need to include it in validate_login.php file also?

Comment: Core PHP is a good thing to know but unless you tap into community code, like from [Composer](https://getcomposer.org), you're missing out on 99% of what makes PHP a useful programming language. Writing, and often painfully and badly re-implementing everything, is not a productive use of your time. What you're describing here is a solved problem. You should find a solution that fits your requirements.

Comment: Yes, you do √ .

Comment: @tadman Okay sure. I will check and learn any of the Framework. Thank you tadman.

Comment: @aidinMC yup it's working now. thank you.

Comment: you're welcome...

Answer (score 0):

Begins the session, you need to say this at the top of a every page or before you call session code

> session_start();

put a user id in the session to track who is logged in

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user']=$user_id; // You can set the value however you like.
header("Location:dashboard.php");
?>
```

**dashboard.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['user'];
?>
```